# How do I bottom-align bars in a CSS vertical bar chart?

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with two different bar charts I created using HTML and CSS: horizontal and vertical. How do I move the bars in my vertical bar chart from the center to the bottom?

[image]

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Global */
.stat-table-horz, .stat-table-vert {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.bar {
     background: #0c0;
}

/* Horizontal bar chart */
.stat-table-horz td:first-of-type {
    padding: 5px;
}
.stat-table-horz td:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-top: 1px solid #090;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #090;
    padding: 0;
    width: 240px;
}
.stat-table-horz td .horz-bar {
    height: 30px;
}

/* Vertical bar chart */
.stat-table-vert tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.stat-table-vert tr:first-of-type td {
    border-left: 1px solid #090;
    border-right: 1px solid #090;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px;
    width: 80px;
}
.stat-table-vert td .vert-bar {
    
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="stat-table-horz">
    <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td>
            <!-- First bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 10%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attack</td>
        <td>
            <!-- Second bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 90%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Speed</td>
        <td>
            <!-- Third bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="stat-table-vert">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- First bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 10%;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Second bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 90%;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Third bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 60%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td>Attack</td>
        <td>Speed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

My original JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkantner/b7aa2yu1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding vertical-align: bottom to the containing TD seems to do it if I'm understanding you correctly.

```
.stat-table-vert tr:first-of-type td {
    border-left: 1px solid #090;
    border-right: 1px solid #090;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px;
    width: 80px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
.stat-table-vert td {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so it looks like I really don't need my .vert-bar class then? Thanks! I was in need of a way to alter those vertical bars.

Comment: for what you want to do...no

Answer (score 0):

Add flowing css

```
.stat-table-vert td {
        position: relative;
    }
    .stat-table-vert .bar.vert-bar{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

or

add

```
.stat-table-vert td {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7aa2yu1/4/

Answer (score 0):

Using `vertical-align: bottom;` or `vertical-align: baseline` on the `td` element should fix the issue.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Global */
.stat-table-horz, .stat-table-vert {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.bar {
     background: #0c0;
}

/* Horizontal bar chart */
.stat-table-horz td:first-of-type {
    padding: 5px;
}
.stat-table-horz td:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-top: 1px solid #090;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #090;
    padding: 0;
    width: 240px;
}
.stat-table-horz td .horz-bar {
    height: 30px;
}

/* Vertical bar chart */
.stat-table-vert tr:nth-of-type(2) td {
    padding: 5px;
}
.stat-table-vert tr:first-of-type td {
    border-left: 1px solid #090;
    border-right: 1px solid #090;
    padding: 0;
    height: 160px;
    width: 80px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.stat-table-vert td .vert-bar {
    
}
```

```html
<body>
<table class="stat-table-horz">
    <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td>
            <!-- First bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 10%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Attack</td>
        <td>
            <!-- Second bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 90%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Speed</td>
        <td>
            <!-- Third bar -->
            <div class="bar horz-bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="stat-table-vert">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- First bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 10%;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Second bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 90%;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Third bar -->
            <div class="bar vert-bar" style="height: 60%;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Health</td>
        <td>Attack</td>
        <td>Speed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

- [Vertical align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)